# How do I avoid Late Binding?

Tags: vb.net, binding

```
For Each drCurrent In chatID.Rows
    LastChatIDCheck = drCurrent("mid")
Next
```

`drCurrent("mid")` is apparently late binding in VB.net. How do I avoid this?

Comment: We have no idea what Type `chatID` is or what Type `LastChatIDCheck` is declared as.  If `chatID` is something like a datatable, `drCurrent("mid")` will return Object since it needs to be able to hold int32, strings etc.  Convert it to whatever data type `LastChatIDCheck` expects.

Comment: Both are declared as Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if you could avoid the late binding problem but you could use the Field extension to the DataRow class.

With the Field extension the returned value is strongly typed, and, at least at the code level you don't have a result stored in an object type.

```
Dim LastChatIDCheck As Integer 
For Each drCurrent As DataRow In chatID.Rows
    LastChatIDCheck = drCurrent.Field(Of Integer)("mid")
    Console.WriteLine(LastChatIDCheck)
Next
```

Also, a good practice to apply everywhere is to turn on Option Strict in the compiler options of your program